# Insert a tableA into another tableB with a different structure

Tags: sql, union, sql-insert, unpivot, lateral-join

I have a table A looks like :

```
 id isin    typ1    typ2                                                                                 
  1 aa      typA    typB                                                                                 
 2  bb      typD    typC
```

I need to insert into a table B that looks like:

```
id  isin    fld     value                                                                                
 1   aa     typ1    typA                                                                                 
 2   aa     typ2    typB                                                                                 
 3   bb     typ1    typD                                                                                 
 4   bb     typ2    typC
```

Can I do with an SQL instruction?

Comment: INSERT with a SELECT ... UNION ALL ...

Comment: what is the result you expect?

Comment: @Giovanni . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The most generic approach is `union all`:

```
insert into tableb (id, isin, fld, value)
select id, isin, 'typ1', typ1 from tablea
union all select id, isin, 'typ2', typ2 from tablea
```

If your database, which you did not disclose, supports lateral joins, this can be more efficiently done using this feature. A typical syntax would be:

```
insert into tableb (id, isin, fld, value)
select a.id, a.isin, x.fld, x.value
from tabla a
cross join lateral (values ('typ1', typ1), ('typ2', typ2)) as x(fld, value)
```

The exact syntax for lateral joins varies across databases.

Comment: i'm using MS Acces and the first solution does not work, I do not know why.... The problem seems linked to the INSERT INTO part...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function along with `UNION ALL` in order to insert the values unpivoted and id values renumerated

```
INSERT INTO tableB(id, isin, fld, value)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY isin, fld), A.* 
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT isin, 'typ1' AS fld, typ1 AS typ FROM tableA UNION ALL
   SELECT isin, 'typ2'       , typ2        FROM tableA
  ) AS A
```